# How to add multiple table with different data-set to the same sheet in exceljs

Tags: angular, export-to-excel, exceljs

I have a button to export a excel file with the data(JSON format). I can able to do for one table but I want to have multiple tables(different datasset-JSON) in the same excel sheet and export that file as shown below.

[image]

I'm using exceljs and file-saver with angular2 in node environment. please guide me with the right approach. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar question and got the answer to it - [Angular xlsx - multiple json to sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54074240/angular-xlsx-multiple-json-to-sheet/54094219#54094219)

Your case is a bit different as you need to play around with merging cells, but there is the option to create the second json with empty props like:

```
let obj = { Name: 'Johnson', '': '', Age: 32, '', '' }
```

Not pretty and not ideal as it will only fit the format of the columns.
However there are few ideas on the web for merges - https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/416

Hope this helps.